# Ordering then Grouping in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to order mysql then group it. this is my table :

```
|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|No|
|consultantid|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|startdate|datetime|Yes|NULL
|enddate|datetime|Yes|NULL
|target|varchar(255)|No|
|dateinserted|datetime|No|CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
== Dumping data for table consultant_targets

|1|1|2016-11-01 00:00:00|2016-11-29 00:00:00|10000|2016-10-31 21:34:55
|2|1|2016-10-31 00:00:00|2016-11-23 00:00:00|15000|2016-10-31 22:03:09
```

The second record is inserted later than the first, and thats what i'm looking to get - so if there was 50 of these it would just grab the latest one. This is my SQL :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ct.*,
        u.username,
        u.colorcode 
    FROM
        consultant_targets ct
        INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = ct.consultantid
    ORDER BY
        dateinserted desc
) AS ctu
GROUP BY
    consultantid
```

But im just getting the first row every time, the one with the 10000 target

Comment: There is no reason to add an `ORDER BY` clause to a subquery. SQL Server disallows it and I imagine MySQL ignores it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT t.*,
       u.username,
       u.colorcode
FROM consultant_targets t
INNER JOIN user u 
 ON u.id = t.consultantid
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM consultant_targets s
                 WHERE t.consultantid = s.consultantid
                   AND s.dateinsereted > t.dateinsereted)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, perfect